# two dropdowns on one dependent dropdown codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I have this dependent dropdown function where I have a dropdown and another one depending on it,

here is the HTML

```
            <select class="form-control" name = "PROV_ID" id = "PROV_ID">
              <option></option>
                <?php foreach ($content2 as $cs) {?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $cs->PROV_ID; ?>"><?php echo $cs->PROVINCE; ?></option>
                <?php } ?> 
            </select>

              <select class="form-control" name = 'CT_ID' id = 'CT_ID'>
                  <option value=""></option>
              </select>
```

and here is the javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#PROV_ID").change(function() {
    var PROVID = {"PROVID" : $('#PROV_ID').val()};
    console.log(PROVID);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: PROVID,
      url: "<?php base_url(); ?>Employees/dependent_dropdown/",

      success: function(data){
          var select = $('#CT_ID');
          select.html('');
          $.each(data, function(i, option){
              select.append("<option value='"+option.CT_ID+"'>"+option.CITY+"</option>");
          });
      }
     });
   });
 });
```

now I want to have one like this, but I wanted to have selected values for the first two dropdowns before the dependent one shows the values.

e.g.

`first dropdown` -->select a value
`second dropdown` -->selects a value

`dependent dropdown` --> gives values according to first and second dropdown.

example: `select * from thistable where column1 = 'firstdropdownvalue' and column2 = 'seconddropdownvalue'`

then the dropdown values would be the result.

Comment: For front-end problems, please post the output HTML, not the php which makes it.

Comment: Do you want third drop down is depend up on two drop downs?

Comment: @KajaMydeen yes thats what i want. :)

Comment: where is the dependent dropdown code html??

Comment: please read it again. my html just involves php because, the values are from database

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#CT_ID").change(function() {
    var PROVID_two = {"PROVID" : $('#PROV_ID').val(), "CT_ID" : $('#CT_ID').val()};
    console.log(PROVID);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: PROVID_two,
      url: "<?php base_url(); ?>Employees/dependent_dropdown2/",

      success: function(data){
          var select = $('#PROVID_two');
          select.html('');
          $.each(data, function(i, option){
              select.append("<option value='"+option.CT_IDnew+"'>"+option.CITYnew+"</option>");
          });
      }
     });
   });
 });
```

You can try like this. Pass two selected values. Hope you understood

Comment: i think i cant do this. bec my variable is `$data = $_POST['PROVID'];` and my query is `$sql =  "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE PROV_ID = '".$data."' ORDER BY CITY ASC";`